como puedo poner una validacion para mi codigo antes de enviarlo a un controlador para que este haga update?
tengo una pregunta con respecto a este codigo siguiente
@For Each item In ViewData("Delete")
   @<tr>
      <td align="center">@item.IDEmployee</td>
      <td align="center">@item.EmployeeName</td>
      <td align="center">@item.Password</td>
      <td align="center">@item.Role</td>
       <td class="Status3"><a href="/EditUser?IDEmployee=@item.IDEmployee">Eliminar</a></td>
        <td class="Status4">
            @if (item.Role = "Admin") Then
    
              Dim isAdmin = True
    
             Else
               Dim isAdmin = False
    
              End If
              <a href="/EditUser?IDEmployee=@item.IDEmployee&EmployeeName=@item.EmployeeName&Password=@item.Password&role=@item.Role&isAdmin=@isAdmin">Editar</a>
             </td>
           </tr>
         Next 

como ustedes podran observar es una tabla en la que jalo informacion de un controlador para poder visualizarla en una tabla hasta ese punto no tengo ningun problema despues necesito enviar la informacion de nuevo al controlador para que vaya ahora a la pestaña de update para modificar el usuario de la aplicacion y/o eliminarlo enviando la informacion tampoco tengo problema mi problema es que cuando mando la informacion necesito hacer una validacion para que no me falle eh intente borrar toda la bd o intente actualizar sin realizar algun cambio pero esta variable o esta comprobacion necesita hacerse desde la vista para que la valide antes de enviarla y al enviarla reconosca que no debe enviar la informacion todavia por lo que me pregunto si alguien tiene idea de como hacerlo intente con algunas variables booleanas que me suena lo mas logico pero me marca un error en el href de la etiqueta a que manda los datos de la vista de nuevo al controlador el error dice que no esta declarada la variable pero segun yo se declara con un valor especifico dependiendo de las condicionales del IF alguno de ustedes sabe como puedo solucionar esto busque informacion pero como es un problema mas especifico de mi app no hay informacion. gracias de antemano alomejor no soy muy bueno y es algo muy x para ustedes pero agradeceria la ayuda

Toda validacion se tiene que volver a hacer en el back, no podes confiar nunca en lo que manda el usuario, pues tiene el control de cambiar lo que manda... una vez dicho esto, no entendi que trataste o que tratas de hacer...
